# I want the program to read the user input using many strings

Tags: java, string

I want the user input to be read and from there the if statements will take over 
but it is not reading the String. I will be adding more station in different zones. help!

```
import java.util.*;

public class centralline {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("What station do you need to know the zone of? ");
        String answer = input.nextLine();
        String zone1 = "Liverpool Street" + "Oxford Street" + "Bank";
        String zone2 = "Mile End" + "Stratford";

        {
            if (zone1.equals(answer)) {
                System.out.println(answer + " is in Zone 1");

            } else if (zone2.equals(answer)) {
                System.out.println(answer + " is in Zone 2");
            } else
                System.out
                        .println("is"
                                + answer
                                + "a Loodon underground station? Maybe check your spelling. ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "it is not reading the String" mean? Please be specific as to what is not working, and what you expect it to do.

Comment: What is an example of the user input?  Just _"Liverpool Street"_ or _"LiverpoolStreetOxfordStreetBank"_

Comment: What do you mean it's not reading the String? As of right now how your code is i see that it won't compile

Comment: Also, please format your code, especially indentation (do not use tabs) - I did it for you this time

Comment: I want to create a problem were the user will input a station name and the program would tell the user what zone is in station. I can only can use if statement.

Answer (score 2):

Either store your `zones` in `String Arrays` and check to see if the answer is in the `Array` or use `.contains()` not `.equals()`.

```
if (zone1.contains(answer))
```

...

```
 } else if (zone2.contains(answer)) {
```

Or:

```
String[] zone1 = new String[3];
zone1[0] = "Liverpool Street";
zone1[1] = "Oxford Street";
zone1[2] = "Bank";

for(String a : zone1)
{
    if (a.equals(answer))
    {
         System.out.println( answer+" is in Zone 1");
         break;
    }
}
```

Just repeat the steps for other zones...Create a `boolean` variable to keep track of whether `answer` was found in one of the `zones`.

Comment: Why downvote the correct answer? At least say why u downvoted it's not helping anyone unless you give an explanation...

Comment: I cannot use arrays in this project, do you know anyway I would be able to do this using if statements?

Comment: @ErnestasSavukas yes look at option 1. Use `contains()` instead of `equals()`.

Comment: Okay, I understand. Thank you so much.

Comment: @ErnestasSavukas you're welcome! Please mark this answer as correct if it helped you...

Answer (score 1):

You could use methods if you dont want to use arrays:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("What station do you need to know the zone of? ");
    String answer = input.nextLine();

        if (isZone1(answer)) {
            System.out.println(answer + " is in Zone 1");

        } else if (isZone2(answer)) {
            System.out.println(answer + " is in Zone 2");
        } else{
            System.out
                    .println("is "
                            + answer
                            + "a Loodon underground station? Maybe check your spelling. ");

        }
}

public static boolean isZone1(String zone)
{
    if(zone.equals("Liverpool Street") || zone.equals("Oxford Street") || zone.equals("Bank"))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
public static boolean isZone2(String zone)
{
    if(zone.equals("Mile End") || zone.equals("Stratford"))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

or you can just move the logic inside your program, if you dont want to use arrays/methods:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("What station do you need to know the zone of? ");
    String answer = input.nextLine();

        if(answer.equals("Liverpool Street") || answer.equals("Oxford Street") || answer.equals("Bank")) {
            System.out.println(answer + " is in Zone 1");

        } else if(answer.equals("Mile End") || answer.equals("Stratford")){
            System.out.println(answer + " is in Zone 2");
        } else{
            System.out
                    .println("is "
                            + answer
                            + "a Loodon underground station? Maybe check your spelling. ");

        }
}
```